# Creating data from tests accessible after tests execution

Tags: apex, unit-test

I would like to gather some info regarding tests execution, e.g. how long execution of different parts of test methods take (e.g. data creation phase, business logic itself, assertion phase).

The idea is to add appropriate logic right inside test methods to measure duration of specific parts. But the problem is where to save this data to make it available for review/reports after tests execution. Due to rollback happened at the end of test phase, custom object is not an option.

The only option I've come up so far is writing to logs (i.e. System.debug) and then fetch info from there somehow. But that's not a good solution for production instance for number of reasons.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

And thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: as long as you are not using `seeAllData=true`, why does it matter if you instrument the test setup creation and asserts in PROD?  The time that will take should always be less then/equal the time taken in sandbox.

Comment: No, it's not about not getting test code instrumented in production. What I mean is that relying on logs in production is not a good idea. Cause logs can be turned on just for 24 hours (plus performance penalty when they are on), after that you need manually set tracing period again for that particular user. What I need is the ability to gather test stats info for days/weeks for further inspection.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you believe the performance of a test will change (beyond the usual non-deterministic variations due to the platform) over a given time period? I'm assuming your tests are creating a constant and well-defined amount of test data (ie. not using `seeAllData=true`). This is starting to sound like you have serious concerns about your code and the volume of data it needs to handle. In that case, it's probably better to start tracking the various `System.Limits` and asserting against them in your tests.

Comment: @DerekF It's just to observe how the performance of business logic evolves in time, e.g. with new releases being deployed to easily identify performance degradation. Also could be other scenarios, like new workflow creation (right in production, which is a bad practice, but looks like not for our client), trigger activation/deactivation etc. basically any changes in prod env, which could influence performance.

Comment: @DerekF One more. We also have this so called "feature togglers" based on custom metadata type, which allows you to turn on/off separate features. It's like when you deploy now, but activate feature later. This could also influence performance in tests.

Answer (score 1):

I think writing to the system log is currently your only option.

- Salesforce doesn't allow emails to be sent from tests (this throws an exception if you try)
- You also can't make callouts from unit tests
- `@isTest(seeAllData=true)` gives you access to live data, but does not get around the data rollback.

Comment: But logs can be activated just for 24-hour period, then you need to go and set tracing period dates again for that specific user. But I need to gather this info for days/weeks, i.e. have a long history of test execution stats available without human interaction.

Comment: @wesaw If you open the developer console, it automatically sets up some default logging levels for you. You could then run your test, and check/download the log (right click the line in the log tab, download is the third option for me). Like I said, I don't think you have any other options here. About the only other thing I can think of is developing your own client that uses the SOAP or REST APIs to execute the tests (log retrieval seems to be a challenge though) and process the results.

Comment: The idea is to gather stats during midnight automated test execution e.g. in production when no one is around, and then just get a nice email in the morning saying if you have any significant performance degradation in comparison with previous runs.

Answer (score 1):

After some back-and-forth in the comments, I think this is something of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Code performance isn't typically going to be something that changes quickly unless you've implemented a O(n^2) algorithm (or, perish the thought, worse than that). With a constant amount of test data, it's also something that will be hard to detect in tests.

Depending on the number and scope of the other changes being made, you might not see any significant difference in your code's performance for weeks, months, or years (and it might not be a single event, but rather a slow change over time). The signal-to-noise ratio would be abysmal, and I don't think it would prove too useful.

Instead, I'd switch focus and start working towards including, in your tests, assertions against the limits that you can poll through [the system Limits class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm).

Given a constant amount of test data, and your well-defined code, you should be able to work out approximately how many queries, query rows, DML, CPU, etc... you expect to be using (ok, the CPU one is harder to pin down, and takes some trial and error).

From there, you can either set your assertions so that they target being able to handle a certain volume of data

> ex. I need to handle up to 5000 records at a time (single SFDC transaction), and this code is run 
>   from a trigger, so a single execution of my code, and everything it
>   interacts with, can consume no more than 4 queries)

or, you can observe what your code currently utilizes, and set a threshold

> ex. My code currently uses `x` number of SOQL queries between it and everything it interacts with. If this number increases by `n`, we need to take a look at things.

Combine this with a Continuous Integration tool like Jenkins (and ANT, look at [this official Salesforce Dev blog for details](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/setting-up-jenkins-for-force-com-continuous-integration.html)), and this should take care of the signal-to-noise ratio issues by only alerting you when your tests fail.

Comment: would Tooling API invoked from a custom client help OP? results could be saved in persistent store then

Comment: @cropredy I thought of that possibility in a comment on my other answer, but I'm not sure if you can get the test logs through the API.